# How to calculate NA's in each column and drop columns having more than 100 NA's

Tags: r, na

Dataset attribute headings

[image]

I am a beginner and I am trying something like this:

```
for (i in newTrain) {
 count = 0
 count = length(which(is.na(newTrain$i)))
 names(-which(count>100))
}
```

but this isn't working at all for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: newTrain[apply(newTrain, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x))<=100)]

Comment: @LourdesHernández no need to use `apply` to `sum` on each `column`, there is a `colSums` function (see the posted answer)

Answer (score 3):

We could first apply `is.na` for the entire dataframe and then `sum` the value of `NA`s for every column. Then select columns which have `NA` value less than 100.

```
newTrain[colSums(is.na(newTrain)) < 100]
```

Comment: Its working...but it was missing a comma newTrain[,colSums(is.na(newTrain)) < 100]  Thank you

Comment: @MuhammadWasif that is strange. It works for me with/without comma.

Comment: @RonakShah It works on a `data.frame` but not on a `matrix`. In either case, you’ll need a `, drop = FALSE` at the end — otherwise this won’t work when only a single column remains.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see, so `newTrain[,colSums(is.na(newTrain)) < 100, drop = FALSE]` would be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Mr. Zheyuan Li .. please dont do this.. I was struck in this small problem since yesterday and he helped me and I find it great support

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Well this question is *not quite* a duplicate.